# Getting rid of duplicates inside List<> contained within a dictionary

Tags: c#, list, dictionary

I have the following dictionary.

```
Dictionary<string, List<string>> dictSubjects = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
```

and I am trying to get rid of potential duplicates residing within each list instace of the respective dictionary entry.

This is what I have tried but get and error along the lines of the list being read only

```
foreach (var kvp in dictSubjects)
        {
            lstSubjectsNoDupes.Clear();
            for (int i = kvp.Value.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                if(lstSubjectsNoDupes.Contains(kvp.Value[i]))
                {
                   lstSubjectsNoDupes.Add(kvp.Value[i]); 
                }
            }
            kvp.Value = lstSubjectsNoDupes;

        }
```

How can I effectively get rid of potential duplicates within each list of  my Dictionary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way if you don't care too much about efficiency would be:

```
dictSubjects = dictSubjects.ToDictionary(pair => pair.Key,
                                         pair => pair.Value.Distinct().ToList());
```

Alternatively, to update the existing dictionary:

```
foreach (var key in dictSubjects.Keys.ToList())
{
    dictSubjects[key] = dictSubjects[key].Distinct().ToList();
}
```

Note the use of `ToList` here to avoid iterating over a view of a collection which is being modified. Without this, `InvalidOperationException` is thrown.

Answer (score 1):

What about

```
foreach (var kvp in dictSubjects.ToList())
    dictSubjects[kvp.Key] = kvp.Value.Distinct().ToList();
```

Comment: This will throw an InvalidOperationException because you're modifying the collection as you iterate over it.

Comment: Oops, true. Added .ToList()